# javaxt image throwing exception

Tags: java

I am trying to resize an image using the javaxt.io.Image library. I am getting with the following code

```
//resizing image using a factor
                if ((fileSizeInMB>=2)&&(fileSizeInMB)<=4)//if the size is between 2 and 4
                {
                    factor=3;
                    image.resize(image.getWidth()/factor, image.getHeight()/factor);

                    image.saveAs(saveDirectory
                            + emaReceiverUtility.getNameOfAttachment(emailMessage)
                            + "_" + fileName);

                }
```

the following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at javaxt.io.Image.getWidth
```

Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong?
What the code is trying to do is to divide the width and the height of the image by a factor. In this case the factor is 3. But the code is not working and I am having an exception at the following line

```
image.resize(image.getWidth()/factor, image.getHeight()/factor);
```

Comment: No, image is created using Image image=new Image(fileName);

Comment: You say that, but the only way that you could get an NPE is if `image` is `null`, since `getWidth()` returns an `int`.  (You may also have issues with integer division down the road.)

Comment: @Makoto if image is `null`, the exception would not be thrown inside `getWidth()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what is going on here. When creating an instance of image, I just provided a name, instead of pointing a real image file.
I changed the code like the following and now it is working.

```
int factor=1;
                Image image=new Image(part.getInputStream());

                log.info("the file name is "+fileName);
                //resizing image using a factor
                if ((fileSizeInMB>2)&&(fileSizeInMB)<=4)//if the size is between 2 and 4
                {
                    factor=3;
                    image.resize(image.getWidth()/factor, image.getHeight()/factor);

                    image.saveAs(saveDirectory
                            + emaReceiverUtility.getNameOfAttachment(emailMessage)
                            + "_" + fileName);

                }
```

Now the only problem is the code is not saving the resized image. It keeps saving the old non-resized file.
[EDIT]
It is actually saving the file correctly, I just forgot a portion of code somewhere that re save the original file and since both files have the same name, the resized file is replaced all this time letting me think that the code is not working properly. Thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

The file does not exists.

Regards